# Filter - how can the result be null instead of an array of size 0

Tags: java, android, filter

Here's my simple filter class inside my adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<T>
{
    private List<T> origItems;
    private List<T> filteredData = null;
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

    public AdapterAppOrContact(Context context, List<T> items)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.row_adapter_app, items);
        origItems = items;
        filteredData = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    // ....

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter 
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) 
        {
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            final List<T> list = origItems;
            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>(count);
            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                filterableString = list.get(i).getName();
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) 
                {
                    newList.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }

            results.values = newList;
            results.count = newList.size();
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) 
        {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<T>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

When you look at `final ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>(count);` this means, this filter can never return a `null` list as far as I see it. But I see following: after `publishResults` is called, my `filteredData` is null.

How can this happen? `filteredData` is private and is not changed in any other place than in the constructor of my adapter and in the filter's `publishResults` callback.

Any ideas? I can solve it with a null check, but I'm curious what the reason is

**Edit - Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.app.package.adapters.AdapterAppOrContact.getCount(AdapterAppOrContact.java:40)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:828)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6373)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
    at com.app.package.adapters.AdapterAppOrContact$ItemFilter.publishResults(AdapterAppOrContact.java:129)
    ...
```

Comment: post your FilterResults  class code

Comment: Is the environment multi-threaded?  And you're saying you're calling `publishResults` with a non-null value?  How do you know that, are you using a debugger?

Comment: `FilterResults` is a class nested in the base `android.widget.Filter` class. And I don't know that `publishResults` is called with non null but I know because of a crash report, that the `notifyDataSetChanged` afterwards will notify the adapter whcih will access the `filteredData` variable and this crashes with a `NullPointerException` because `filteredData` is null

Comment: @markspace you're right, the filtering is done asynchronously, still, there is no place I set the `filteredData` to null and the `publishResults` is called on the main thread (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#publishResults(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.Filter.FilterResults))

Comment: One possible explanation is that `publishResults(..)` is not called at all.  Could that happen if `performFiltering` through an unchecked exception?  What happens if `items` / `origItems` is `null`?

Comment: @StephenC I added the stacktrace, this is not the case

Comment: So some possibilities I see are: publishResults is not being called, it's being called on another thread and set to null, or it's not an Adapter but a sub-class which overrides publishResults.  (The latter could happen if you're using any framework that uses byte-code weaving.)  You need to set a break point in a debugger or using logging/println to be sure of each call to that method.

Comment: You have shown us of the application code in that stacktrace

Comment: Added this code. Stacktrace shows anyway, that the variable is null which is important. I'm getting the stacktrace from a user device, only once until now... I can't reproduce this, I never had a crash on my device

Comment: I think you need to add some logging to `publishResults` and send the log file along with the crash.  Something is setting that value to null.  Do you ever create an Adapter with a null value via a ctor?  There could be a timing issue of when getCount() is being called.

Comment: [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic adapter is what you need